# Why won't my Label containing pyimage1 image object pack and display on the frame, when other labels containing text will?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to display the image passed from the MainFrame class to the CheckImageFrame class using the open_file and switch_frame methods. The object is a PIL PhotoImage/pyimage1 object.

I would like to understand why the Label with the "this is page one" text in the CheckImageFrame class will pack successfully, but the image will not.

Thanks in advance!

```
class WaterMarkGenerator(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self._frame = None
        self.switch_frame(MainFrame)

    def switch_frame(self, frame_class, image=None):
        # Destroys the current frame and replaces it with a new frame
        new_frame = frame_class(self, image)
        if self._frame is not None:
            self._frame.destroy()
        self._frame = new_frame
        self._frame.pack()
        

class MainFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, image):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        master.title("Watermark Generator")
        Label(self, text="Please upload an image to watermark.").pack(pady=30)
        Button(self, text='Upload a File', command=self.open_file).pack(expand=True)

    def open_file(self):
        self.file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(
            initialdir='/',
            filetypes = (
                ('JPEG', '*.jpg'),
                ('PNF', '*.png'),
                ('All files', '*.*')
            )
        )
        if self.file_path is not None:
            try:
                self.image = Image.open(self.file_path, mode='r')
                self.tkinter_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)
                self.master.switch_frame(CheckImageFrame, image=self.tkinter_image)
            except IOError:
                pop_up_window()


class CheckImageFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, image):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        Label(self, text="This is page one").pack(fill="x", pady=10)
        Label(self, image=image).pack(fill='x', pady=50)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep a reference to the image inside `CheckImageFrame` so it is not collected by pythons garbage collector:

```
class CheckImageFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, image):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.image = image # Keep reference
        Label(self, text="This is page one").pack(fill="x", pady=10)
        Label(self, image=image).pack(fill='x', pady=50)
```

I posted an answer even though this is a duplicate of the popular question, [Why does Tkinter image not show up if created in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424091/why-does-tkinter-image-not-show-up-if-created-in-a-function), because the implementation of that answer here could be tricky as the image seems to have reference in all the other classes except `CheckImageFrame`.

Alternatively:

```
class WaterMarkGenerator(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        ...

    def switch_frame(self, frame_class, image=None):
        # Destroys the current frame and replaces it with a new frame
        self.image = image # Hold a reference here itself
        new_frame = frame_class(self, self.image)
        ...
```